# Raspbian - Execute .py file from PHP code

Tags: php, python, raspbian

after many research, I come here for a helping hand. I'm working on a Raspberry PI 3 with the latest raspbin OS. I have a web server ( Appache, MySQL, PHP ) running fine on it.

I try to execute a .py file from PHP code, however, it does not work. I tried to change file location to /var/www/html, I added www-data exception to sudoers, I added

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

in start of my .py file, I tried change file ownership to give it to www-data, I tried to change www-data to a root user, but my .py still does not execute.

My .py file work fine via SSH or direct execution.

Here is how I launch it

```
exec('sudo -u www-data python /var/pi/www/html/Currenttestpy.py', $out, $status);

echo 'Status : ' . $status . '.' ;
```

it return me a "1" status. I trie the same code with pi user, same result. Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: I think the problem will be with that `sudo` statement. The PHP script will be running as another user and can't elevate itself to root. BUT... Shouldn't the PHP script already be running as www-data?

Comment: Well, a helping hand come from IRC : the matter come from my command. I captured stderr appending 2>&1 in the end of my command, 

exec('sudo -u root python /var/www/html/Currenttestpy.py 2>&1', $out, $status);

and the error was clear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running without elevating to root?

```
exec('python /var/pi/www/html/Currenttestpy.py', $out, $status);

echo 'Status : ' . $status . '.' ;
```